# Find the second smallest integer in an array. Returns wrong value for 2nd smallest integer

Tags: java

I need to find the **second smallest number** in an `array` using java.  I have the following code.  It sort of works but for some reason it does not go through the array a second time completely to find the second smallest value.  It stops at the 3rd index and returns that value instead.  As you can see the second smallest value is at index 14.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

// Java program to find first and second smallest number in an array

```
public class FindSmallest2 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                 int[] values;
                 values = new int[15];   
                 values[0]=341;            
                 values[1]=273;
                 values[2]=278;
                 values[3]=329;
                 values[4]=445;
                 values[5]=275;
                 values[6]=275;
                 values[7]=243;
                 values[8]=334;
                 values[9]=412;
                 values[10]=393;
                 values[11]=299;
                 values[12]=343;
                 values[13]=317;
                 values[14]=265;
                 int small1, small2;
                 small1 = small2 = values[0]; 
                 for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) 
                     {
                         if(values[i]<small1) 
                         {
                             small2 = small1;
                             small1 = values[i];
                         }
                     }
                         System.out.println("1st smallest value: "+small1);
                         System.out.println("2nd smallest value: "+small2);
          }
      }
```

Comment: You hardcoded the values, you already know what's the second smallest value :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun it's to check if the code works

Comment: As an improvement hard-coded array initialization can be written as: `int[] values = {1, 2,..}`. More readable...

Comment: @jeankaleb which one works? accept it as answer.

Answer (score 7):

You don't account for the case in which the tested number `values[i]` is not the smallest, but it's smaller than the current 2nd smallest number.

Here's a possible fix :

```
if (values[i]<small1) {
    small2 = small1;
    small1 = values[i];
} else if (values[i]<small2) {
    small2 = values[i];
}
```